# numpy.dot() gives TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

I have just begun learning Machine Learning using Python. I have written the following class which gives an error:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

```
class Perceptron(object):
    def __init__(self, eta=0.01, n_iter=10):
        self.eta = eta                          # Learning Rate
        self.n_iter = n_iter                    # Number of iteration over the training dataset

    def fit(self, x, y):
        self.w_ = np.zeros(1 + x.shape[1])      # Initialize Weights to zero initially                                                # x = {array-like} : shape[no_of_samples, no_of_features]
        self.errors_ = []                       # No errors in the beginning of the computation
        for _ in range(self.n_iter):
            errors = 0
            for xi, target in zip(x, y):
                update = self.eta * (target - self.predict(xi))
                self.w_[1:] += update * xi
                self.w_[0] += update
                errors += int(update != 0.0)
            self.errors_.append(errors)

        return self

    def net_input(self, x):
        return np.dot(x, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]

    def predict(self, x):
        return np.where(self.net_input(x) >= 0.0, 1, -1)
```

I am getting an error in the net_input() method at np.dot(). 
I am using the following dataset :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv

Comment: is `x` of the correct dimensions? see [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading the training data (data and predictions) from the file iris.csv

```
sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.9,3,1.4,0.2,setosa
```

with:

```
data = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")
```

make sure that you define `x` as the first four columns, otherwise it will contain the strings from the last column:

```
X = data.iloc[:,0:4]
```

And prediction values:

```
y = data.iloc[:,5]
y = y.values.reshape(150,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following changes would help.

```
def fit(self, x, y):
    ...
    for xi, target in zip(x, y):
        update = self.eta * (target - self.predict(xi.reshape(1, x.shape[1]))
        ...

# Here if you want to implement perceptron, use matmul not dot product
def net_input(self, x):
    return np.matmul(x, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]
```

Comment: `np.dot` is element-wise multiplication `np.matmul` is matrix multiplication. Here in this special case `(1, n)(n, 1)`  it would be same; NOT OTHERWISE

Comment: For element-wise multiplication dimensions of the matrices have to be same. `np.multiply` is the element-wise multiplication. (Operator is `*`). For matrix multiplication result of `np.dot` and `np.matmul` (Operator is `@`) are same.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `shape` of `x`.

If it is `(a, 1)` where `a` is a number, use this:

```
def net_input(self, x):
    return np.dot(x.T, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]
```

If it is `(1, a)` use this:

```
def net_input(self, x):
    return np.dot(x, self.w_[1:].T) + self.w_[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `x` is an object dtype array of lists.

If I define an object dtype array:

```
In [45]: x=np.empty((2,),object)
In [46]: x[:]=[[1,2],[3,4]]
In [49]: x
Out[49]: array([list([1, 2]), list([3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

I get the same error with a list (or array) of floats:

```
In [50]: np.dot(x, [1.2,4.5])
...
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

If instead I give it integers, it works - sort of

```
In [51]: np.dot(x, [1,2])
Out[51]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4]
```

What it has actually done is `[1,2]*1` and `[3,4]*2`, list replication.  This is not numeric multiplication.

That's the only combination of variables that makes sense of the error message.

So you need to figure out why `x` is an object array.  Often that's the result of building an array from lists that differ in length

```
In [54]: x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4,5]])
In [55]: x
Out[55]: array([list([1, 2]), list([3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

So the basic question when faced with an error like this, what's the `shape` and `dtype` of the variables.