# How to write a class that makes numpy's dot() use my __rmatmul__()?

Tags: numpy

What is the simplest way to make numpy's `dot()` method use my object's `__rmatmul__` method?

The issue is easily demonstrated with `scipy.sparse`:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) 
B = sparse.diags([1, 2])

BA = B.dot(A)          # Works fine
AB = B.__rmatmul__(A)  # Works: This is what I want to happen
AB = B.T.dot(A.T).T    # Works but not simple
AB = A @ B             # Preferred way for Python 3.5+
AB = A.dot(B)          # This is what people do, but it gives very non-intuitive results
```

The desired result here is `B.__rmatmul__(A)` but I do not want users used to using `numpy.dot` to get tripped up when the reasonable expression `A.dot(B)` returns a 2x2 array where each element is a sparse matrix (a copy of B):

```py
>>> AB
array([[<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>,
        <2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>],
       [<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>,
        <2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>]], dtype=object)
```

If I am writing my own "sparse" class, how can I get numpy to use my objects `__rmatmul__` function?  From the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40380014/1088938), it seems like the only solution might be to make my object a [subclass of np.ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html), but this seems way too complicated (and may still fail since I doubt I can provide sensible view-like access to a sparse array).

*(The particular application I would like to use is a custom sparse representation of an array as a sum over dyads, but the details are not important.)*

## References

This issue has been pointed out several times, and the result explained in terms of the behaviour of `numpy.dot()`, but the solutions are all workarounds.  None answer this question.

People running into this issue:

- [scipy.sparse dot extremely slow in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204406)
- [numpy.dot() gives TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754359)
- [Dot product between scipy sparse matrix and numpy array give ValueError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55776220)

Ugly workarounds:

- [numpy: formal definition of "array_like" objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378427): Formal definition of "array-like" objects as far as `numpy` is concerned, but this seems to require that my object behave as a dense array of numbers (defeating the purpose of a sparse implementation).
- [Array and __rmul__ operator in Python Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229953): Subclass `ndarray` (with warnings).
- [Commute numpy sparse matrix dot product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682378): Suggests essentially `B.T.dot(A.T).T`.

**(Update)**

I think in Python 3.5 and above it is clear that one should used the notation `A @ B` instead of `dot()`.  The question still remains for earlier versions of python, but is less relevant.

- [Why is a.dot(b) faster than a@b although Numpy recommends a@b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062496): It is not significantly slower for large enough matrices.
- [Difference between numpy dot() and Python 3.5+ matrix multiplication @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142485):
- [PEP 465 -- A dedicated infix operator for matrix multiplication](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465)
- [NumPy dot documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html): Recommends `A @ B` or `matmul()` for 2-D arrays.

Comment: The problem is that `A.dot` isn't an operator.  It does a naive `np.array(B)`, instead of using `B.A` or deferring to B's own method.

Comment: Even using `A @ B`, a complete answer will need to discuss [`__array_priority__`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/c-info.beyond-basics.html?highlight=__array_priority__#the-array-priority-attribute).

Comment: @mforbes Did you ever workout how to do this?

Comment: @TomMcLean No, but I have not looked at this for a while.  The situation might be better now.